# What is a Rainbow table? How many hash codes must be generated in the following scenario?

Tags: password-management

One of the technical access controls used by a company consists of entering a 5-digit PIN. When entered, the PIN number is hashed and the hash code is compared to the stored value of the hash code in the system. To produce a rainbow table for the hash codes of all the possible 5-digit PIN configurations, how many hash codes must be generated?

Comment: No rainbow table needed - you just need 10^5 entries in your table to have all possible hashes. That's tiny. Rainbow tables are only needed when you have so many results that you need reduce memory by adding additional computation.

Answer (score 4):

The total character length is `10` since these are the available digits:

`0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9`

`10^5` = `100,000`

So about `100k` hashes. You don't need [rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) for this, though, but you should read up on them for a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the Rainbow Table: the number of hashes in a hash-chain is **not** fixed. Might be (theoretically) any number; though the number of chains and number of hashes per chain have a great influence on the performance.

In your case generating a Rainbow Table is quite an overkill though. This kind of software is usually applied for **way** greater sets of passwords. In your case the alphabet is `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` with a fixed wordlength of 5, thus there are `10^5 = 100000` valid words. The small number of valid words allows the generation of a simple lookup-table or derivation of the password via a simple brute-force-attack.

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul. However, how the alphabet {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} is chosen with the 10 base? if the elements in the set of numbers is an assumption, is this the same technic applied in all the cases?

Comment: @ShanthamurthyHanumantharayapp PINs usually consist of digits, thus the alphabet is `[0-9]`. Though the content of the alphabet isn't relevant here. The important point is just the number of words that can be used as valid passwords

Comment: Thanks Paul now I am clear about Rainbow Table functionality. And why is this named after Rainbow?

Comment: Never mind Paul I figured out, since the Rainbow table is new to me and I was interested in digging deep to understand the concept. Thanks for all your answers.